# How to convert general number to HH:MM:SS format using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one column in general number format and unable to convert that in HH:MM:SS format. It can be achieved in excel, but do not know how to do in pandas.

```
data['AHT']
0.003549
0.003162
0.003533
```

The above column is converting to time format in excel like shown below

```
00:05:07
00:04:33
00:05:05
```

Please help me on how to get the same output in pandas. It is also ok if it comes only in seconds format as shown below.

```
307
273
305
```

Comment: Is there any meaning to the words AHT is it some sort of time format?

Comment: No, it is just a column name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number is a fraction of the day and you want seconds:

```
data.AHT * 86400
```

Comment: If you want the ```'%H:%M:%S'``` format: ```from datetime import timedelta``` then ```timedelta(seconds=round(0.003549 * 86400, 0)).__str__()```  results in ```'0:05:07'```

Answer (score 1):

using pandas Timestamp:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Timedelta(days=0.003549).total_seconds()
>> 306.6336 # nanosecond precision
pd.Timedelta(days=0.003549).__str__()
>>'0 days 00:05:06.633600'
```

using Datetime module

```
from datetime import timedelta
timedelta(days=0.003549).__str__()
>>'0:05:06.633600' # HH:MM:SS format with nanosecond precision

timedelta(days=0.003549).seconds
>>306
```

Note that pandas Timestamp class is alternate to python's Datetime module

Comment: Please fix this answer or withdraw it. For starters it is ```from datetime import datetime```. This is evident from your second line: ```datetime.fromtimestamp```.  Also neither of  your examples actually return the correct value of ```00:05:07```.  This is because ```datetime.fromtimestamp()``` works with POSIX timestamp which is seconds since UNIX epoch(1/1/1970 00:00:00) and the time in the question is from Excel and and is a fraction of a day.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for pointing out the fault. My earlier answer was based on POSIX timestamp

Comment: Which is not what the question was referring to. Understanding what is being asked for and what the conditions are is the most important part of this process. Also not all that enthusiastic about you recycling my solution as your own without any credit given. Finally the last line is now confusing as you are no longer using pd.Timestamp. For these reasons I will be down voting this answer.